# Implication Graph Assignment

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, tarjans-algorithm, implication, 2-satisfiability

An implication graph is a directed graph where each node is assigned either true or false and any edge `u -> v` implies that `if u is true then v is true`.

I know a straightforward `O(n^2)` algorithm to find an assignment in a general implication graph and `O(n)` algorithms for some special cases (like the implication graph arising from a *2-SAT* problem).

So I was wondering if there is an `O(n)` algorithm find assignment of any implication graph?

Comment: You didn't specify what are the requirements for the assignment.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of an implication graph that is not equivalent to a 2-SAT problem?  (I thought all implication graphs are equivalent to 2-SAT and can all be solved in O(n) by Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm)

Comment: @piotrekg2, each edge specify a requirement. An edge from node u to node v means if u is assigned true then v must be true also.

Comment: How is that not equivalent to the 2SAT formula (!a OR !b) AND (!b OR c)? The general idea is to replace x -> y with !x OR y.

Answer (score 1):

Satisfying assignments for implication graphs can be found using the [Tarjan strongly connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Strongly_connected_components) method since that method is applicable to all implication graphs, not just those produced via conversion of 2-SAT instances.  That method consists of a small number of graph conversion steps, all of which require time linear to the size of the input.  Thus the algorithm as a whole requires O(n) runtime.